# how to increase the y axis of a plot after getting plot?

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have a plot in MATHEMATICA.  I want to edit a plot to increase the y-axis. The editing should be possible after plot.

Comment: Please include a copy of your code by editing your post. Click the grey question mark on the right side of the editing toolbar for help with proper formatting.

Answer (score 3):

you can change the value of y_min and y_max to change the range on y axis (see below). Btw, instead of posting an open ended or a vague question, try to post your code to demonstrate your effort

```
Plot[(* your function comes here *), PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin ,ymax}}]
```